# How can I transform one line JSON to pretty print in linux shell?

Tags: json, linux, shell, unix, command-line

Lets say I have file something like this:

```
{"c_me": "2018-02-02T14:48:21.267790Z","et": "192.168.2.6:34097"}
```

And I want the file to be

```
{
  "c_me": "2018-02-02T14:48:21.267790Z",
  "et": "192.168.2.6:34097"
}
```

How can I do this in a short way?

Comment: `jq . your-file` ?

Comment: in only makes output, but I need to change a file

Comment: `jq . your-file > your-file.tmp ; mv your-file.tmp > your-file`

Comment: thanks very much, it works